# Can a existing mapreduce program be made to run from a specified offset of input file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, hadoop2

Is there any way to run an existing mapreduce program so that it processes only from a given offset of the input file?

Eg:
If given offset is 500, the mapreduce program should start processing input file from 500th byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but will require Java coding and creating a custom InputFormat. For example you can subclass FileInputFormat and override methods **public List getSplits(JobContext job)** and **protected FileSplit makeSplit(Path file, long start, long length, String[] hosts)**.
To pass the starting offset you can use Configuration parameters accessible via **job.getConfiguration().getInt(YOUR_PARAM_NAME, 0)**

Comment: Thanks a lot alexeipab,can the byte offset configuration parameter be given in oozie workflow? I just want the changes to existing mapreduce programs to be minimum.

Comment: I think oozie allows you to put values into the Configuration context or job.xml or other, do not remember exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Not According to my knowledge, but it might be possible.

A possible workaround is creating a static variable to count the number of bytes and skipping the number of bytes by casting your mapper input as byte array.